# "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10" option not present

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I am currently using an ASUS X552CL which came pre-installed with windows 8. I had installed windows 7 pro, and then upgraded to windows 10.

I am trying to dual-boot my PC with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (64-bit), but during installation, it says, "This computer doesn't have any OS. What do you want to do?". Also, if I try the "something else" option, it does not detect my partitions (I had partitioned 30 GB to install Ubuntu using the windows disk management tool). All I see is my hard disk in it's entirety.

Honestly, I am new to this, and have been trying to find solutions for a few days now. Thus far, I have disabled hibernate.

I have used

```
sudo apt-get install gdisk
```

within the Ubuntu Live desktop, and it finds a valid MBR and a corrupt GPT.

Also, I have found that a BootInfo summary would be useful for people who may assist, so I have generated one using the Boot-Repair tool. Mine can be found here: [paste.ubuntu.com/14135768](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14135768)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds familar to me. Based on the output of your log, it seems you have two boot table entries.

1 MBR and 1 GPT.

Stated here

> GUID Partition Table detected, but does not seem to be used

and

> WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util
>   fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

First of all, I would give your BIOS a look up and check if there are multiple bootable disks to choose. In my case, I had a gpt table on a stick and a MBR on the HD, solution was simple to select the MBR as the first bootable device instead of the gpt (or vice versa)

The second advice is to run the Microsoft Bootloader correction tool or (what I prefer) the liveDVD rescatux, which repairs almost everything automatically regarding GRUB, MBR etc.[SuperGrub/Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) there is also a huge wiki about all common boot problems [Wiki](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/Boot_Problems)